# Windows phone 8 retrieving image from web service?

Tags: image, web-services, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set the source attribute of an Image element to an image in my localhost, basically what I'm doing is display a list with items, their description, price and an image. I get all these values from a web service which returns the url where the image is in the local server Eg: http://localhost/roses.png, when the list of items is displayed all values are set correctly but the Image element does not show the image.

Web service returns the data in JSON format. Eg: 
[{"ImagenUrl":"http://localhost/roses3.png", .... ]

code on client_actionCompleted method:

```
if (e.Result != null)
        {

            dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);

            foreach(var v in jsonObj)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE URL ==>  " + (string)v.ImagenUrl);

                FlowersItems fi = new FlowersItems();
                fi.fi_name.Text = (string)v.Nombre;
                fi.fi_price.Text = (string) v.Precio;
                BitmapImage tn = new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)v.ImagenUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

                fi.fi_image.Source = tn;

                FlowersItemsListbox.Items.Add(fi);
            }

        }
```

As I said before the fi_name and fi_price text is set correctly but the fi_image is not displayed even though I can view the image in my browser going to the url returned by the web service just fine.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Edit: just in case, I also tried new Uri((string)v.ImagenUrl)
without the UriKind.Absolute parameter.

Comment: have you tried binding the `BitmapImage` to the XAML code directly..? I suggest instead of adding `FlowersItemsListbox.Items.add(fi)`, you should assign `ItemsSource` to `FlowersItemsListbox`. That will work for sure.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON Value that you received for binding the `(string)v.ImagenUrl` is correct? Could you post a sample JSON your XAML code Code where you BIND.

Comment: @Jerin The JSON response returns the correct value, I copied this:[{"ImagenUrl":"http://localhost/roses3.png", .... ] when the WS was executed by doing a Debug.WriteLine. I would post the whole JSON but now I can't even get the WS to run, I don't know if in every reboot a different port is assigned to IIS express :(